# Make Docker compose wait for PostGIS (PostgreS) in Django project

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgis

I need to write a shell script that will allow docker to wait for postgres database.
I have a following shell script named *wait-for-postgres.sh* :

```
#!/bin/sh
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e
  
host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"
  
until PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done
  
>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

*docker-compose.yml :*

```
  version: '3'
  services:
    db:
      image: kartoza/postgis:12.0
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=amr_or
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    web:
      build: ./
      command: bash -c " ./wait-for-postgres.sh && python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --i rest_framework &&  gunicorn orion-amr.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=2"
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      env_file:
        - ./.env.dev
      depends_on:
        - db
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2.7
WORKDIR /orion-amr/
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
COPY wait-for-postgres.sh /wait-for-postgres.sh
COPY . /orion-amr/
```

How to add my existing commands from docker-compose.yml (python manage.py ..., etc) to shell script?

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having?  You should be able to add more commands to the script before the final `exec` line.

Comment: Exactly. I dont understand how to add additional commands to the script. 
Another problem is I dont know if my script is correct or not

Answer (score 1):

Use [pg_isready](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/app-pg-isready.html)

In *Dockerfile* add:

```
RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-client
```

In *wait-for-postgres.sh*:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

### WAITING POSTGRES START ###
RETRIES=7
while [ "$RETRIES" -gt 0 ]
do
  echo "Waiting for postgres server, $((RETRIES--)) remaining attempts..."
  PG_STATUS="$(pg_isready -h $host -U postgres)"
  PG_EXIT=$(echo $?)
  echo "Postgres Status: $PG_EXIT - $PG_STATUS"
  if [ "$PG_EXIT" = "0" ];
    then
      RETRIES=0
  fi
  sleep 5  # timeout for new loop
done

### DJANGO MANAGE COMMANDS ###
python manage.py makemigrations && 
python manage.py migrate && 
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --i rest_framework && 
gunicorn orion-amr.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=2
```

In *servive web* from *docker-compose.yml* remove **command** and add **entrypoint**:

```
version: '3'
  services:
    db:
      image: kartoza/postgis:12.0
      environment:
        - POSTGRES_DB=amr_or
        - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
        - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      ports:
        - "5432:5432"
    web:
      build: ./
      entrypoint: ["bash","./wait-for-postgres.sh"]
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      env_file:
        - ./.env.dev
      depends_on:
        - db
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have written should be used as an [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) in Docker. If you run this script as `ENTRYPOINT`, then your commands from docker-compose.yml file will be passed as `$cmd` in the entry point script.

```
FROM python:2.7
WORKDIR /orion-amr/
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y binutils libproj-dev gdal-bin
COPY wait-for-postgres.sh /wait-for-postgres.sh
COPY . /orion-amr/
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-postgres.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/wait-for-postgres.sh"]
```

And remove that script from `docker-compose.yml`:

```
command: bash -c " python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --i rest_framework &&  gunicorn orion-amr.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=2"
```

Comment: Unfortunaly, now it says "standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"

Comment: I have updated the answer with chmod. Please check this link as well: https://forums.docker.com/t/standard-init-linux-go-175-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file/20025

Answer (score 0):

First better to place the `CMD` in the Dockerfile and override when required from the docker-compose file.

so Dockerfile will look like

```
RUN chmod +x /wait-for-postgres.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/wait-for-postgres.sh"]
CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "migrate",  "&&",  "python", "manage.py", "collectstatic",   "--noinput",  "--i",  "rest_framework", "&&", "gunicorn", "orion-amr.wsgi:application", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--workers=2"]
```

or if you want to run with compose then you do not need specify `bin/bash` as you already consuming the `CMD` in bash script.

```
    web:
      build: ./
      command: "python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --i rest_framework &&  gunicorn orion-amr.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=2"

      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      env_file:
        - ./.env.dev
      depends_on:
        - db
```

So the now if you inspect the container the `CMD` will look like

```
            "Cmd": [
                "python",
                "manage.py",
                "makemigrations",
                "&&",
                "python",
                "manage.py",
                "migrate",
                "&&",
                "python",
                "manage.py",
                "collectstatic",
                "--noinput",
                "--i",
                "rest_framework",
                "&&",
                "gunicorn",
                "orion-amr.wsgi:application",
                "--bind",
                "0.0.0.0:8000",
                "--workers=2"
            ]
```